# Fancybox 2 not showing title for a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to show title for image in fancybox but it doesn't show and I can't find out why...

This is my HTML

```
<div id="gallery">
  <table style="border:none">
    <tr>
      <td style="vertical-align: middle; border=none; background-color:white;">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group1" href="/path/to/image.jpg">
          <img src="/path/to/image.jpg" alt="my alt text" width="100" height="100" />
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

and this is Fancybox code

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    hideOnContentClick : false,
    openEffect : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    maxWidth : 900,
    autoSize : false, 
    helpers : {
        title: {
            type: 'outside'
        }
    },
    beforeShow : function() {
        this.title = "Nananana Batman";
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: *sidenote:* incorrect CSS. should be `border: none` instead of `border=none`.

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine http://jsfiddle.net/axGUB/ most likely you have other CSS settings that voids the fancybox title. BTW, you don't have any `title` attribute in your `<a>` tag so fancybox gets the `title` from the `beforeShow` callback.